# SSH Command From PHP not working. Command runs fine from command line

Tags: php, command-line, ssh, unzip

I inherited this intranet app which unzips some requested spooled reports and dumps them into a Samba folder users have access to. Here's the PHP:

```
$command = "$unzip_program $path_spooled/$zip_file $filename -d $target_dir";
$ssh_command = "$ssh_syscommand -i /web/live/sshkey_nopass reportuser@$archive_server \"$command\"";

$sshpipe2 = popen( $ssh_command, 'r' );
```

So if I echo the SSH command being run it's:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /web/live/sshkey reportuser@192.168.1.21 "/usr/bin/unzip -c /reports/spooled/2012/jan.zip 01SU7C.RPT" |
/usr/bin/ssh -i /web/live/sshkey reportuser@192.168.1.2 "cat > /reports/spooled/01SU7C.RPT"
```

(I inserted a carriage return after the pipe for readability)

If I execute that command from the command line it works fine. If run from php it fails with no errors.

All I need is some help working out where to look. I figure it could be a missing ssh key, but the server does show a login from that user when the command is executed.

What am I missing? Where should I look? Is there something about unzip I don't know about? Do I need to set some sort of context from Apache?

Comment: what is `echo` or `print_r` return about `$command` and `$ssh_comand` variables?